# how to search case insensitive in hibernate search using lucene query?

Tags: java, lucene, hibernate-search

I am using two analyzers while indexing such as `StandardAnalyzer` for some fields and `WhitespaceAnalyzer` for some fields holding value as special character like `c++` but I am writing query as

```
QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Professional.class).get();
BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();

query = qb .keyword().wildcard().onField(fieldName).ignoreFieldBridge().matching(fieldValue+"*").createQuery();
booleanQuery.add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
```

the above query returns results are different as case sensitive like c++ And C++ 
so i want acheive case insensitve for results,because of i am not using same analyzer while indexing as well as searching ,so am i wrong

plz help me because i get strucked from 1 week plz...
thanks in advance

Comment: public class MyAnalyzer extends Analyzer {
  Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer() {
      protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(final String fieldName) {
          Tokenizer source = new WhitespaceTokenizer();
          TokenStream filter = new LowerCaseAnalyzer(source);
          return new TokenStreamComponents(source, filter);
      }
  }

}   I added above code like as mentioned but i got error like The type MyAnalyzer must implement the inherited abstract method Analyzer.tokenStream(String, Reader) so how to resolve it

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I was using keyword().wildcard() for one field and faced the issue that **not** in lowercase written word could not be found.
The solution was very simple - instead of implementing Analyzer I converted search term to lower case before writing any query. In your case it would look like this:

**fieldValue = fieldValue.toLowerCase();**

QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Professional.class).get();
BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();

query = qb.keyword().wildcard().onField(fieldName).ignoreFieldBridge().matching(fieldValue+"*").createQuery();
booleanQuery.add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

Answer (score 0):

You should use a custom analyzer and add LowerCaseFilter after the WhitespaceTokenizer.  Like this:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer() {
    @Override
    protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(final String fieldName) {
        Tokenizer source = new WhitespaceTokenizer();
        TokenStream filter = new LowerCaseAnalyzer(source);
        return new TokenStreamComponents(source, filter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, how to use your code and which place i put these code,plz help me because  i used annotation as @Analyzer(impl = WhitespaceAnalyzer.class)
 @Field
 private String skill;

Comment: can you explain in detail with example Thanks in advance

Comment: i am using  hibernate serarch 4.4.6 so i used custom analyzer but it shows must implement the inherited abstract method Analyzer.tokenStream(String, Reader) my custom analyzer code is   public class MyAnalyzer extends Analyzer{
 Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer() {
     @Override
     protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(final String fieldName) {
         Tokenizer source = new WhitespaceTokenizer();
         TokenStream filter = new LowerCaseAnalyzer(source);
         return new TokenStreamComponents(source, filter);
     }
 }
}           Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As of Hibernate 5.10.3, the syntax has slightly changed for creating custom lucene analyzer:

```
public class CustomAuthorAnalyzer extends Analyzer {

    @Override
    protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(final String fieldName) {
        Tokenizer source = new WhitespaceTokenizer();
        TokenStream filter = new LowerCaseFilter(source);
        return new TokenStreamComponents(source, filter);
    }
}
```

Then in order to use this analyzer on a custom field, we just need to specify it through `@Analyzer` annotation:

```
@Analyzer(impl = CustomAuthorAnalyzer.class)
@Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
private String author;
```

Hope that helps.

Alternatively, lucene also provides a mechanism to easily compose a new custom analyzer:

```
public static Analyzer create() throws IOException {
    Analyzer ana = CustomAnalyzer.builder(Paths.get("/path/to/config/dir"))
            .withTokenizer(WhitespaceTokenizerFactory.class)
            .addTokenFilter(LowerCaseFilterFactory.class)
            .addTokenFilter(StopFilterFactory.class, "ignoreCase", "false", "words", "stopwords.txt", "format", "wordset")
            .build();
     return ana;
 }
```

The builder class is pretty easy to use for creating a composite analyzers.

More information here: https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_4_2/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/custom/CustomAnalyzer.html

Comment: Does hibernate automatically discover any custom analyzer classes you've made? How do you implement this?